# How to select a function using active record in codeigniter?

Tags: php, postgresql, codeigniter, activerecord

I have a Postgres SQL Query and need transform it to active record, how to achieve this?

Example:

```
SELECT * FROM abc(1,2,3) as (a float, b float, c tinyint)
```

Need in object mode to prevent SQL injection.

Comment: I've removed my answer, because the escaping example I gave is working with `mysql`, but I've not seen you tagged the question with `postgresql` (which I'm not familiar with). Make sure your database setting (dbdriver) is correct and read also about escaping with CI: https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/queries.html?highlight=escape#escaping-queries

Comment: still thinking about how to resolve this: if this is feasible, try: `$query = $this->db->select('* FROM abc, 1 as a, 2 as b, 3 as c') `